# ¿Por qué en PHP la expressión "2 + '6 manzanas'" es 8?

Tags: php

En PHP, cuando hago la suma abajo, el resultado es extraño:

```
$manzanas = 2 + '6 manzanas';
```

El resultado es:

```
8
```

Pero si hago como abajo, el resultado es diferente:

```
2 + 'seis(6) manzanas'
```

Resultado:

```
2
```

¿Por qué el PHP tiene ese comportamiento?

Comment: De foro o stackoverlor otro lenguaje: 1.deseas sumar un string siendo un programado de 4 a;os 2. utilizastes especificamente comillas simples que toman el string de forma literal 3.vuelves a cometer el error pero esta vez con seis(6) 4.no sabes porque sucede pero sigues texteando los diferentes resultados 5. ya habias hecho la misma pregunta en stackoverflow portugues [porque 2+'6 manzanas'](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80767/por-que-no-php-a-express%C3%A3o-2-6-ma%C3%A7%C3%A3s-%C3%A9-igual-a-8) 6. tus preguntas son elaboradas pero tus respuestas son ultra basicas! deduccion traduces!

Comment: @Bryro es el sitio en portugués. Y [esta respuesta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80772) de la autoría de Wallace confirma que él conocía cómo funciona PHP. No es que la pregunta no se pueda hacer aquí, pero si se conocía la respuesta se podría haber hecho una pregunta/respuesta bien documentada.

Comment: @A.Cedano 1. revisando en la web la pregunta no vino del es una traduccion como sospechaba! sus preguntas son traducciones de otras preguntas hechas en otros idiomas con mira el perfil y compara las preguntas solo cambiado a  otros idiomas bum! mas de 15 coincidencias le dare el beneficio de la duda argumentando que tiene 17 nombres y a olvidado sus contrase;as y correos! lo malo es que no se puee marcar como dupliado porque es diferente idioma :v

Comment: Hice la pregunta para ayudar a la comunidad. Hago lo mismo en el otro sitio. Lo siento por la confusión

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esto sucede básicamente porque el operador **+** *(Identidad)*  realizará la conversión a entero o `float` según sea el caso, para este caso hace el `cast` a entero.

Se emplea la función [intval($valor)](http://php.net/manual/es/function.intval.php) , si esta función retorna error que es el caso del segundo ejemplo, **retornará 0**, por lo cuál estaría sumando `2+0`.

Para el primer ejemplo se debe tener el cuenta el párrafo de la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/function.intval.php).

> Las cadenas muy probablemente devolverán 0, **aunque esto depende de los
>   carácteres del extremo izquierdo de la cadena**. Aplican las reglas
>   comunes para [moldeado de enteros](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting).

Como inicia en 6 se realiza el `cast` e ignora el resto de la cadena, al final retornará **6**, y se realizará la suma `2+6` que da como resultado `8`

Answer (score 5):

El intérprete de **PHP** es lo suficientemente inteligente como para que, al tratar de sumar un **entero** con una **cadena**, vaya a intentar convertir la **cadena** en algo con lo que pueda operar matemáticamente.

```
$manzanas = 2 + '6 manzanas';
```

En este caso, empezaría a leer la **cadena** capturando el número **6**, pero al ver que el resto es algo que no puede transformar en un número dejaría de interpretarlo, ignorándolo del todo.

Por eso:

```
string '6 manzanas' = int 6;
```

En el segundo caso que plasmas, el número se encuentra integrado en mitad de la **cadena** por lo que el intérprete no es capaz de extraerlo para tratar de operar con el matemáticamente, ignorando la cadena por completo.

Por eso:

```
string 'seis(6) manzanas' = int 0;
```

**Referencia:** http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Comment: Más que *inteligente*  yo le llamaría *permisivo o hasta atrevido. PHP me parece muy flojo con el manejo de tipos, posiblemente esto tenga sus razones, pero no es nada bueno ni inteligente, yo prefiero que de un error en ambos casos a que me sume valores según su *inteligencia*.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. He modificado la introducción de mi respuesta para no otorgarle a **PHP** cualidades que no tiene.