# ¿Como quitar (.00) de un campo decimal Laravel?

Tags: php

Buenas Tengo un proyecto donde me muestran los siguintes dantos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en los valores del campo **CANTIDAD RECARGA** quiero eliminar el punto y los dos 0 la derecha , es decir , el lugar de que me muestre **2000.00** nesesito que solo muestre **2000**

**funcion que me manda los datos a la vista**

```
public function index()
    {
        $usuarios = Usuario::with('recargas')->get();
        return view('recargas.index' , compact('usuarios'));
    }
```

**vista**

```
<br>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('recargas.create') }}"> Nuevo recarga  </a>
<br>  
<br>
<table class="table table-hover">
   <thead class="thead-dark">
      <th scope="col" >Id</th>
      <th scope="col" >Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col" >Cantida Recarga</th>
      <th scope="col" >Fecha Recarga</th>
      <th scope="col" >Acciones</th>

   </thead>
   <tbody>
      @foreach ($usuarios as $usuario)
         @foreach ($usuario->recargas as $recarga)
            <tr>
               <th scope="row"> {{$recarga->id}} </th>
               <td>  {{ $usuario->nombre . " " . $usuario->apellidos}} </td>
               <td> {{$recarga->cantidad_recarga}} </td>
               <td> {{$recarga->fecha_recarga}} </td>
               <td>             
                  <form action="{{ route('recargas.destroy' , $recarga->id) }}" method="POST">
                        <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('recargas.edit', $recarga->id) }}">  Actualizar  </a>

                        {{csrf_field()}}
                        @method('DELETE')
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Eliminar</button>
                  </form>

               </td>
            </tr>
         @endforeach
      @endforeach
   </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede utilizar una función de `PHP`, [floatval()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.floatval.php) para obtener el valor flotante de su campo `cantidad_recarga`.

Esta función obtiene el valor flotante de una **cadena** pasada por parámetro, realizando una conversión *(cast)* a `float` , tomando algunas [reglas](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) ya definidas. Algo muy similar a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/235088/por-qu%C3%A9-en-php-la-expressi%C3%B3n-2-6-manzanas-es-8/235099#235099) que un usuario realizó pero con la conversión de enteros.

```
<td> {{floatval($recarga->cantidad_recarga)}} </td>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://rextester.com/PSRF76145)**</kbd>

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono , pero me podrias explicar que es lo que hace exactamente esa función.

Comment: Obtiene el valor flotante de una cadena pasada por parámetro, realizando una conversión a float , tomando algunas [reglas](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) ya definidas. Algo parecido a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/235088/por-qu%C3%A9-en-php-la-expressi%C3%B3n-2-6-manzanas-es-8/235099#235099) pero la conversión ya seria un tema más extenso que se escapa de la pregunta.