# Calculo de horas en php

Tags: php

Esta función me dá dos errores

```
<?php
function calculohoras($hora_inicio, $hora_final){
  $datetime1 = new DateTime($hora_inicio);
  $datetime2 = new DateTime($hora_final);
  $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
  return $interval->format('%H:%I');
}

$horas = calculohoras("2019-05-21 08:00:00", "2019-05-21 17:30:00");
$pausa = calculohoras("2019-05-21 13:30:00", "2019-05-21 14:30:00");

$total = $horas - $pausa;

echo $total;
?>
```

El primer error me dice lo siguiente:

```
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

El segundo error es que según los cálculos que he hecho en total serían 8:30 horas y me lo redondea a 8, no quiero que me lo redondee.

¿Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function calculohoras($hora_inicio, $hora_final){
  $datetime1 = new DateTime($hora_inicio);
  $datetime2 = new DateTime($hora_final);
  $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
  return $interval->format("%H:%I:%S"); 
}

$horas = calculohoras("2019-05-21 08:00:00", "2019-05-21 17:30:00");
$pausa = calculohoras("2019-05-21 13:30:00", "2019-05-21 14:30:00");   
$total = calculohoras($horas, $pausa);

echo $total;
```

Te encontrabas cerca de conseguirlo. Con unas pequeñas modificaciones hice que la función `calculohoras()` devolviese la diferencia entre fechas en un formato que me permite construir con él un objeto `DateTime`.

Luego, con los valores recuperados vuelvo a calcular la diferencia entre ellos llamando una vez más a la función `calculohoras()` pasándole las variables `$horas` y `$pausa`, que al ser `string` válidos desde los que crear un `DateTime()` provocará que la función `calculohoras()` funcione correctamente.

**EDIT**

El `notice` no consigo reproducirlo, por lo que asumo que se debe a la resta de `strings` que estabas realizando. El segundo error te ocurría porque estabas tratando de restar dos `strings`, por lo que el resultado no era el que esperabas.

Si quieres saber por qué te hacía la resta parcialmente aunque viniese de dos `strings` puedes echarle un ojo a:

[¿Por qué en PHP la expressión “2 + '6 manzanas'” es 8?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/235088/por-qu%C3%A9-en-php-la-expressi%C3%B3n-2-6-manzanas-es-8/)

Comment: Perfecto! Ese era mi fallo! Muchas gracias!!